# How do you get Windows 7 to format your hard drive on install

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have installed Windows 7 today - but it never asked me if I wanted to format my hard drive like Win XP used to do on setup/install.  What should I have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to boot from the DVD and start the installation that way. If you start the installation from inside Windows it will disable that option.

Second when you get to the drive selection you click on the advanced options button and there you can format the partition.

Comment: ahh yes - never saw the advanced option button first time round.